# Move Hyper-V VMs to a different host, by moving the physical storage

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

I have two systems running Windows 8.1, and old and new. The old box has a couple dozen Hyper-V Virtual Machines (VMs) I used for development/testing.  All the VMs are stored on a 2TB drive that is separate from the OS drive.  With the VHDX files in `D:\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks` and the various hyper-v configs for the VMs in `D:\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines\Virtual Machines`.

I plan on simply disconnecting the drivefrom the old system, and connecting it to the new system.

What isn't obvious to me is how to re-import all the VMs back into Hyper-V on the new system.

Most of the docs I find about hyper-V migration suggests using `export-vm`/`import-vm`, but these commands basically make a full copy of the VHDX files along with the configuration..  For my purposes this is a complete waste of time.  Also, I have insufficient storage space on that system for two copies of everything, and it would take a lot of time for basically no useful purpose.

I could simply create new VMs and point it at the original VHDX files, but there must be some way to automate this.  Re-configuring all the various settings for each VM would tedious, and I would almost certain, miss some setting, since I have lots of VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was over-thinking this problem.  After some additional research I found that nothing needs to do as an export or prepare the VMs before moving the storage.

Migrate instructions.

- Shut down the old system, and pull the drive with the various vhd(x), and xml files in it and transfer it to the new systems.
- On the new system use the [Import-VM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848495.aspx) powershell command with the **-Register** option to re-register the VMs on the new system.

I also found this blog post basically [describing the procedure](http://www.robertborges.us/2013/10/windows/windows-server-2012/importing-exporting-hyper-v-virtual-machines-in-windows-server-2012-r2/).